# trying to set selected option in drop down menu populated with array

Tags: php

I populate drop down menus in standard fashion using foreach loops like the following:

```
// set zone array for drop down menus
$zone = array('NEZ','NWZ','SEZ','SWZ');

<?php
    foreach ($zone as $z) {     // cycle thru array
        echo "<option value='$z'";      // open option tag
        // set default selected
        if ($z == 'NWZ') {
            echo " selected";
        }
        echo ">$z</option>";    // close option tag
    }
?>
```

So no problem with populating the drop down menu, but the NWZ in the example above never gets set as the SELECTED value and I can't see why. At some point (second iteration of array) the IF statement should ring true and that option tag should have the SELECTED attribute assigned to it. Can anyone help with what is surely an obvious faux pas I am overlooking here?

Comment: Should be `$z`, not `$zone`. (*Because `$zone` is an array, while `$z` is the current iterated value*)

Comment: What he is trying to say, is that you are checking whether or not $zone equals 'NWZ' instead of checking $z == 'NWZ'. $zone is an array, not a value.

Comment: Sorry I originally did have it scripted as $z == 'NWZ' and when it was not working as expected I tried a few things including subbing in $zone in place of $z. DOH!

Comment: so it does not work when $z == 'NWZ' either. Updated question to reflect that.

Comment: Try - `selected="selected"` as the value. Also, check the source of the generated HTML, is it present there?